# Как обратиться к глобальной переменной из функции

Tags: c++, c

Как обратиться к глобальной переменной из функции в которой уже имеется переменная с таким же названием? Допустим есть программа

```
#include <iostream>
int q=15;
void main()
{
    int q=10;
    std::cout<<q<<endl;
}
```

Как можно обратиться к глобальной q?

Comment: ``std::cout << ::q << std::endl;`` [тест](https://ideone.com/36hb7a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того что бы обратиться к переменной, которая определена не как локальная в функции, используйте оператор [`::`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/scope-resolution-operator?view=vs-2017) *оператор разрешения области*, перед переменной.

```
#include <iostream>
int q=15;
int main()
{
    int q=10;
    std::cout << ::q << std::endl; // выведет 15
}
```

Для избежания повторных, или же похожих вопросов, дополню, что этот оператор работает не только на локальных переменных, но и на области называемой **namespace**'ами.

Т.е. к примеру, у вас есть класс `window`, а так же есть `namespace window {...`:

```
namespace window
{
    int posX;
    class window
    {
        int posX;
        ...
    }
}
```

Вы так же можете обратиться к переменной расположенной в пространстве имен, прямо из класса, используя этот оператор:

```
namespace window
{
    class window {
        window(...)
        {
            posX = ::window::posX; // для примера
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: так глобальное пространство и есть  безымянный namespace,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, я это имел ввиду, безымянный =)